# Microsoft CRM 2013: relate Account and Contact entities AFTER import

Tags: php, soap, dynamics-crm-2013

I've a cronjob importing from CRM Accounts and Contacts entities but I cannot filnd a way to relate them. **How can I relate them? Is there a third junction entity I have to deal with?** Below there's the complete fields list from Contacts table. I expected somewhere a parent account field but I could not find it anywhere (I read it was a CRM 2011 field that was dismissed).

```
customertypecode
address2_addresstypecode
merged
gendercode
territorycode
emailaddress1
haschildrencode
exchangerate
preferredappointmenttimecode
isbackofficecustomer
transactioncurrencyid
owninguser
importsequencenumber
lastname
donotpostalmail
donotphone
preferredcontactmethodcode
educationcode
ownerid
customersizecode
firstname
yomifullname
donotemail
address2_shippingmethodcode
fullname
address1_addressid
address2_freighttermscode
statuscode
createdon
donotsendmm
donotfax
leadsourcecode
modifiedon
creditonhold
new_salutation_formale
address3_addressid
donotbulkemail
modifiedby
shippingmethodcode
createdby
donotbulkpostalmail
new_contactnumber
parentcustomerid
contactid
participatesinworkflow
statecode
owningbusinessunit
address2_addressid
new_salutation_informale
```

Thanx in advance for your precious help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the `parentcustomerid` field you are looking for. This field can reference an Account as well as a Contact record.

Comment: Great! Tomorrow I'll try to deal with this field, thanx a lot Henk Van Boeijen!

Comment: Update: it works! Thanx a lot again, you've made my day!